# Can you transform a date into local browser time from UTC in a pipe in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime, angular-pipe

So I have a section of code like so in my view:

```
{{ lastUpdatedUTC | date:'hh:mm': 'PST-14:00' }}
```

I know I can pipe in a format from here: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe.  And I know I can also pipe in a decrement.  But is there a way to account for the browsers local time in a pipe conversion as well as handling day light savings?

I know I could do this in the component:

```
var utc = `${x.lastUpdatedUTC}Z`;
console.log(utc);
console.log('PST time: '+ new Date(utc).toLocaleString());
```

Is there a way to do something like that inline?

Comment: Isn't by default when timezone is not supplied it uses the end-user's local system timezone?

Comment: @penleychan Yes and I was curious if the preferred answer may be to specify the UTC DateTime Kind at the service level.  I may go that route as well.  But if the DateTime is NOT specified it assumes it's in your local time already.